# Visualizing a feature/kernel produced by a CNN via an "optimal" input image using Keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, keras

So I've been doing a lot of research regarding the visualization of CNN's and I can't seem to find a solution to what I'm trying to do, or at least to my understanding of the methodologies employed. A lot of it is pretty new and cutting edge, so I could just not be properly grasping the concepts.

Basically, I want to take a learned kernel/feature as trained by a CNN and essentially manufacture an "optimized" picture such that when the kernel is convolved with said picture, we have the highest convolutional sum possible.

If I'm not mistaken, this should exaggerate the features of that kernel on the image level rather than at the filter/kernel level, which seems to be what most have done in terms of visualizing these filters.

In case what I'm asking is not clear, here's an example (probably bad, but it'll get the point across.)

Assume we are using MNIST and I've created a CNN like so:

5x5 Conv with 10 kernels/Feature Maps

Relu

2x2 MaxPool 2 stride

Dense + Softmax

Let's say I've fully trained my model and now want to look at one of the 10 5x5 kernels it produced and get a better idea of what it's looking for. I want to manufacture a new 28x28 picture such that when convolved with this 5x5 kernel, the sum of the 28x28 convolution is maximized.

Are there techniques that already do something like this? I feel like everything I see involves either "unwinding" or "reversing" the neural net (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1311.2901.pdf), viewing the feature maps as pictures pass through (http://kvfrans.com/visualizing-features-from-a-convolutional-neural-network/), or just looking at the kernels themselves (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AgkfIQ4IGaM).

Is it even something useful to look at? I feel like this is the closest thing I've seen to what I'm requesting. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.6034.pdf

Any insight would be a huge help, thanks!

Comment: Hey, i have a question on this specific subject,  maybe you could have some idea ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52206265/visualization-of-a-single-neuron-activation-in-convolutionnal-networks
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called activation maximization, and Keras even has an example of it available [here](https://blog.keras.io/how-convolutional-neural-networks-see-the-world.html). Note that the code in the post might be outdated for current Keras versions, but a updated version is available in the examples folder in Keras.

Comment: This is fabulous, thank you so much! Surprised I never stumbled upon this despite all my searching. You're my hero =D